# How to put where clause for multiple columns while updating multiple columns at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, sql-update

I want to update more than 10 columns at the same time , and my problem is I want to put where clause for all these columns.

My code is:

```
UPDATE Customer AS c
                    SET 
                        name = a.name,
                        address= a.address,
                        telephone = a.telephone,
                        --
                        --
                        --


        FROM Customer a 
                      INNER JOIN 
                        ( SELECT casenumber
                               , max(currentDate) AS md 
                          FROM Customer 
                          GROUP BY casenumber
                        ) AS z 
                      ON  z.casenumber = a.casenumber
                      AND z.md = a.currentDate
                    WHERE (a.casenumber = c.casenumber)
```

In the above statement I want to add condition as to update columns only when they are not 0.

for exmple,

```
UPDATE Customer AS C
    SET name = a.name,
    address= a.address,
    ...

    ..
     WHERE a.name <> 0,
            a.address <> 0, 
            a.telephone <> 0
            ....
            ...
```

Is it possible to put where condition to check each column?

Any suggestions are appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (assuming `name <> 0` is a typo and your names are really character columns)

```
 UPDATE customer AS c
     SET name = CASE WHEN name <> '' THEN a.name ELSE name END,
         address = CASE WHEN address <> '' THEN a.address ELSE address END
```

This essentially updates the column to it's current value if it's empty.

Note that this does not deal with NULL values! If you need to treat NULL and `''` identically you need to use `coalesce(name, '')` instead.